# Condition in a single column in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table name 'social_user' there is a column named 'return' column's screenshot is below-

[image]

I want to count users from social_user table where return equal 0 as new_user and where return is greater than 0 as returning_user and also total user output should like this screenshot:

[image]

I tried below query but it's not working-

```
select count(`return` = 0) as new, count(`return` > 0) as returning from social_user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need conditional sum not count

```
select
sum(`return` = 0) as `new`,
sum(`return` > 0) as returning,
count(*) as total_user
from social_user
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN `return` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS new_user,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `return` > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS returning_user,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `return` >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS total_user
FROM
    social_user
```